# Youtube branding

Tags: security, youtube, jwplayer, youtube-javascript-api

I want to place YouTube video on my site with no branding . also I don't want any one to right click and grabbing the vid URL. JW player will support this but ppl still can click the YT watermark. is thire any way I could add allow networking internal only function to jw play. basically I don't want any onto go to YouTube and also to copy the url

Comment: There is no way to hide the source of the youtube video without downloading it and putting it on a different site. Firebug or Inspect Element (or view source if it is not added dynamically) will allow people to get that.

Comment: You can look into [**this site's guide**](http://www.reelseo.com/remove-youtube-logo/) for removing YouTube logos from your videos.

Comment: Thanks for the reply its still not completely brand free.you can still click and go to youtube site and aslo right click to get the url. I am not worried about the pages sourec code coz I have jS method to hide that. I just want the player to play the video and block users going to YT and right click the player and get the url

Comment: YouTube is not some free hosting service. Their branding is required in order to comply with their Terms of Service.